# How to get parameter of Decision table in Drools before it executed

Tags: drools, jbpm

I am new in Drools and jBPM. I have one question regarding drools decision table. Normally we run rules first and then take a some action on that but i want first some parameter from decision table and based on that i fire mysql query and that gives me some data which i want to pass in drools so is there any way to get data from decision table before it executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using the database from within the decision table. Just insert the results directly to working memory.